# Rails - How to add a format to an url helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, helper, url-helper

how can I make an URL helper create an URL in a given request/response format?

For example, in my test I have the following:

```
get(activity_url(activity))
```

This will returns me an HTML on the `@response` object. I'm looking to have the same behavior of the following:

```
get({controller: 'activities', action: 'show', id: activity.id, format: 'js'})
```

but without all this wording. Is it possible?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
some_resource_path(format: :json)
```

or

```
some_resource_url(format: :xml)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, as the last parameter. Do you know where can I find the docs for this url helpers?

Comment: a shortened syntax 'some_resource_path :json' works too

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Rails/Ruby, so I'm not sure why, but in my Rails 3.2 application the syntax must be eg:

```
some_resource_path(:format => :json)
```

Comment: did you mean `:format => :json`? It is the same than `format: :json`, but with some extra syntax sugar. However, `format: => :json` seems like a syntax error.